# Programmaticaly set a default page layout for publishing pages in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to set a default page layout for publishing pages in SharePoint 2010 programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following, with `layoutName` being the file name e.g. `MyDefaultLayout.aspx`.

```
void SetDefaultPageLayout(string layoutName, SPWeb web)
{
    var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
    if (pubWeb != null)
    {
        var pageLayout = pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts()
            .Single(pl => pl.Name == layoutName);
        pubWeb.SetDefaultPageLayout(pageLayout, true);
        pubWeb.Update();
    }
}
```